# How to improve speed of the following loop in R?

Tags: r, performance

I'm pretty new to R (been playing for some days now) and I'm sorry if this is not the right place to ask such question but didn't know where else to post.

I've been using this loop in R. The thing is it takes approximately a day to run the whole thing. There's gotta be a way to make it more efficient and faster.

It basically simulates 10'000 correlated 1-day ahead returns of 9 variables for a testing period of 570 days.

```
simList <- array(dim=c(570,9,10000)

presigma=matrix(tail(sigma(tmp),1),ncol=9)
prereturns=matrix(unlist(returns[T+i-1,]),ncol=9,nrow=1)
preresiduals=matrix(tail(residuals(tmp),1),ncol=9, nrow=1)
preR=last(rcor(tmp))[,,1]
diag(preR)=1
preQ=tmp@mfilter$Qt[[length(tmp@mfilter$Qt)]]
preZ=tail(tmp@mfilter$Z,1)

for (i in 1:570){
tmp=cgarchfilter(specx, returns[i:(T+i-1),], filter.control=list(n.old=T))
sim <- cgarchsim(fit, n.sim=1, m.sim=10000, startMethod="sample", preR=preR, preQ=preQ,
               preZ=preZ, prereturns=prereturns, preresiduals=preresiduals, presigma=presigma,
               cluster=NULL)
simx=t(sapply(sim@msim$simX, FUN=function(x) x[1,]))
simList[i,,] <- simx
}
```

I've been reading some stuff on vectorization or using the `apply` function, but most examples I've found were applied to rather "simple" loops, and I couldn't understand how to apply the same methodology in my case.

Do you know how I can improve the speed? Would you frame the code a bit differently? What could be extracted from the code and be run outside of it?

**EDIT 1:** Following lmo's comment I've extracted all the objects whose definition stays the same within the loop outside of it. While it is an improvement from a visual point of view and way easier to read, the computation time still remains the same. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT 2:** If you want to try the entire code, here's a minimal working example (I've slightly modified some details such as length of testing horizon because this dataset is not the one I'm working on, but the problem with speed remains the same). In order for the code to work, this code below should be run **before** the one above (below: part 1; above: part 2). Used packages are `rugarch` and `rmgarch`. The dataset comes automatically with these packages.

```
data(dji30retw)
returns = dji30retw[, 1:9, drop = FALSE]
spec=ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1), 
                                  submodel = NULL, external.regressors = NULL, variance.targeting = FALSE), 
            mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0,0), include.mean = FALSE, archm = FALSE, 
                              archpow = 1, arfima = FALSE, external.regressors = NULL, archex = FALSE), 
            distribution.model = "norm", start.pars = list(), fixed.pars = list())
multigarch = multispec(replicate(9, spec) )
spec <- cgarchspec(uspec=multigarch, VAR=FALSE, robust=FALSE, dccOrder=c(1,1),
                  asymmetric=TRUE, distribution.model=list(copula="mvt", method="ML", time.varying=TRUE, transformation="spd"))
fit <- cgarchfit(spec, returns, out.sample=570, spd.control=list(upper=0.9, lower=0.1, type="mle", kernel="normal"),
                cluster=NULL, fit.control=list(eval.se=FALSE))
T=571
specx <- spec
for (i in 1:9)   specx@umodel$fixed.pars[[i]]=as.list(fit@model$mpars[fit@model$midx[,i]==1,i])
setfixed(specx) <- as.list(fit@model$mpars[fit@model$midx[,10]==1,10])
```

Comment: It appears that some lines like `preZ=tail(tmp@mfilter$Z,1)` appear in both branches of the if else and do not change within the loop. If only for ease of reading, you might consider pulling such lines above your loop as a "loop set up" section.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you mean that I could extract those lines (such as preZ) outside the loop even if tmp changes for each i? I thought that since tmp is defined for each i, all other lines have to be redefined also. Could you elaborate a bit what you meant? Just to see whether I understand, thanks!

Comment: Yes. Since these objects do not themselves change, there is no point in calling them up repeatedly. Create them once outside of the loop and then use them in the lines of code that does change.

Comment: Please include all packages you are using. However, it appears like you are doing 10k model fits. That can be expected to be slow. However, if you are not happy with performance, you should profile your code and identify the bottlenecks. If these bottlenecks are the functions `rcor` or `cgarchfilter` you'd need to look for or write faster implementations of these.

Comment: I'm using the rmgarch package, which seems to be the only package with the implementations I need (dynamic copulas). Since my coding skills are very mediocre I'm very skeptical that I could write anything to make it faster. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The posted code in the question won't execute as is (even after library(rmgarch).  Could you please provide a minimal working example?

Comment: Hi @jvd10, I've added the rest of the code, you can find all necessary info in "Edit 2". I've only changed the testing window, before I wanted to forecast 2172 returns, now 570. Apart from this, the code has stayed the same. If something doesn't work (it should work though) please hit me again